# Не работает плагин

Tags: joomla

Не работает плагин:

```
class plgContentCounter extends JPlugin {
    public function onContentAfterDisplay($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart) {
        if ($context == 'com_content.article' && JFactory::getUser()->id == $article->created_by && $params->get('intro_only')) {
            $database = JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = 'UPDATE #__content SET hits = hits - 1 WHERE id = ' . $article->id;
            $database->setQuery($query);
            $database->query();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

XML: `<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">`

Плагин должен блокировать счетчик просмотров (hits), если материал просматривает его автор. Устанавливается нормально, а работать не хочет.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в имени класса - оно точно должно совпадать с именем php-файла плагина.